# Angular 2 - Simplest way to inject single instance of service

Tags: angular

In angular 2.0.0 I have a service called NavService which is shared across multiple components. What is the simplest way to inject a single instance of the service where the single instance is shared across all the components in the application?

Currently I have done following where I have included the service in my app.module.ts file but get an error **Cannot find name 'NavService'** when trying to access it in my Dashboard component.

app.module.ts

```
// Core
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routing } from './app.routing';

// Shared Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './nav/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LayoutDirective, FlexDirective } from './layout.directive';
import { NavToolComponent } from './nav/nav-tool/nav-tool.component';

// Shared Pipes
import { AppFilterPipe } from './app-filter.pipe';

// Shared Service
import { NavService } from './nav/shared/nav.service'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    LayoutDirective,
    FlexDirective,
    NavToolComponent,
    AppFilterPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [NavService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  view: string = 'Dashboard';
  currenView: string = null;
  constructor(private NavService: NavService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Update Current View in Nav Service
    // Send RXJS mesage to nav tool on Change
    this.NavService.updateCurrentView('Dashboard');
    this.view = this.NavService.getCurrentView();
    console.log(this.view);

  }

  testFn(): void {
    this.view = this.NavService.getCurrentView();
    console.log(this.view);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're on the right way, just need to have the `import` line in your Dashboard.

Comment: That was easier than I thought. Thanks !